# Determinant of a matrix whose elements are trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Calculate:
>
> $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
>   \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
>   \cos2\varphi & \sin2\varphi & 2\cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi \\
>   \cos3\varphi & \sin3\varphi & 3\cos3\varphi & 3\sin3\varphi \\
>   \cos4\varphi & \sin4\varphi & 4\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $$

By elementary row operation,it is equivalent to calculate
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \cos2\varphi & \sin2\varphi \\
  -\cos3\varphi & -\sin3\varphi & 2\cos3\varphi & 2\sin3\varphi \\
  -2\cos4\varphi & -2\sin4\varphi & 3\cos4\varphi & 3\sin4\varphi
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Though this form is a bit more convenient for Laplace Expansion, it still requires a lot of effort to obtain the result.

Comment: I would not say it is *a lot* of effort; knowing a few basic trigonometric identities makes it a few minutes worth of work at most. Did you try anything further?

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's *one* way to do it:
\begin{align*}
& \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  \cos2\varphi & \sin2\varphi & 2\cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi \\
  \cos3\varphi & \sin3\varphi & 3\cos3\varphi & 3\sin3\varphi \\
  \cos4\varphi & \sin4\varphi & 4\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  \cos3\varphi & \sin3\varphi & 3\cos3\varphi & 3\sin3\varphi \\
  \cos4\varphi & \sin4\varphi & 4\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & 2\sin\varphi & 2\cos3\varphi & 3\sin3\varphi - \frac{\cos3\varphi \sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  \cos4\varphi & \sin4\varphi & 4\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & 2\sin\varphi & 2\cos3\varphi & 3\sin3\varphi - \frac{\cos3\varphi \sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & \frac{\sin3\varphi}{\cos\varphi} & 3\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi - cos(4\varphi)\tan(x)
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & 0 & -4\cos\varphi\sin^2\varphi & \sin3\varphi - \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \frac{\sin3\varphi}{\cos\varphi} & 3\cos4\varphi & 4\sin4\varphi - cos(4\varphi)\tan(x)
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & 0 & -4\cos\varphi\sin^2\varphi & \sin3\varphi - \sin\varphi \\
  0 & 0 & -2 \sin^2\varphi (3 + 4 \cos2\varphi) & \sin2\varphi (4 \cos2\varphi - 1)
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\
  0 & \tan\varphi & \cos2\varphi & 2\sin2\varphi - \frac{\sin\varphi\cos2\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \\
  0 & 0 & -4\cos\varphi\sin^2\varphi & \sin3\varphi - \sin\varphi \\
  0 & 0 &0 & -\tan\varphi
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & 4 \tan^2\varphi \cos^2\varphi \sin^2\varphi
= 4 \sin^4\varphi.
\end{align*}
While it looks very complicated, notice that all terms of rows 2 - 4, which are above the diagonal, don't really matter, so don't have to be computed explicitly.